# Javascript Facebook Open Graph: Post to wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am following the example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/ and have created an action. When clicking the "Create a story" button and following the link, I see my working action (in this case, I'll just call it "xxx bought a product on xxx").

But this doesn't show up on my wall. Is this because the action isn't fully accepted yet? I have tried to find about fb:explicitly_shared in the Javascript SDK, but can't find any working example.

The reason why it hasn't been accepted yet, is because the reviewer says that it seems to be for testing purposes - which is a full 100% true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to approve the action in the App Settings, after that it will be visible on the wall.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/#submit